# How to use mysql variables in joomla queries

Tags: mysql, joomla3.0

How do I use mysql variables inside of the Joomla! query builder and with `loadObjectList()`?

Comment: A decade ago when StackOverflow was just getting started, this Broad type of question was tolerated.  In fact, you will find many one-sentence questions from that era with hundreds of upvotes.  Times have changed and the expected standard is much higher.  In your question, you should include your failed coding attempt (I assume without `execute()`), the undesired outcome, any notices/warnings/errors, possibly some sample table schema/data, and your desired output.  By posting all of this... 1. Search engines will get better "purchase" on this page 2. Other volunteers will be able to offer

Comment: specific advice and clarify if you have secondary issues to resolve 3. You will be role modeling the kinds of questions that will ultimately lead to the continued success of this site 4. You stand a greater chance of helping others and gaining upvotes.

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple,

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('apses.*,'
        . ' @sess_total_uptime := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, apses_date_created, apses_last_activity) as sess_total_uptime, '
        . ' FLOOR(@sess_total_uptime / 60) as hours, '
        . ' ROUND(MOD(@sess_total_uptime, 60)) as mins '
);
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__mysessions', 'apses'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute(); // <-- This thing is *VERY* IMP
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Where do the `wlusg` and `users` tables come from? There are no JOINs. What happens if you omit the `execute()` method call?  Is `$user_id` cast as an `int` prior to the query?  Please improve your answer to be more accurate and educational.

Comment: @mickmackusa I appreciate your feedback, Have updated my answer to reflect the same. About the Q/A quality, I keep hitting this error every once in a while (almost annually) and since there is no documented solution online I just thought might post this as a resource for future googlers and maybe myself since I keep 'discovering' my own answers from the past, way more often than I'm ready to admit.

Comment: Please improve your answer and question.